# Substituir o segundo caractere repetido

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho o seguinte valor numa consulta Oracle.

```
SELECT '3.0.' FROM DUAL
```

Gostaria que retornasse apenas **3.0** e retirasse o Último ponto (.)

Tentei usar o [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) assim:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('3.0.','(.){2,.}','') FROM DUAL
```

Porém não funcionou. Pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [TRIM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm) da Oracle.

Deixando a query desta forma:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRIM(TRAILING . FROM campo))
FROM tabela
WHERE condições
```

Comment: O trim não remove os espaços que tiver no texto?

Comment: De acordo com a documentação, você pode especificar o que vai ser removido. Se não especificar, ele remove espaços.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer com o [`SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679), removendo o ultimo caractere:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(VALOR, 0, LENGTH(VALOR)-1) FROM (SELECT '3.0.' VALOR FROM DUAL);
```

Veja em funcionamento no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9e8e/2).